# How to do a template multiple inheritance in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, twig, shopware

I have two plugins:

1. XYZ Plugin that is inheriting the Shopware base template/block and
   overriding it.
2. ABC Plugin which I want to inherit XYZ overridden template/block and
   override it.

How can I do this in Shopware 6?

XYZ plugin code in `tabs.html.twig` file:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/tabs.html.twig' %}

{% block page_product_detail_tabs_inner %}
    <div class="detail-accordion" id="accordion">
        {% block page_product_detail_accordion_description %}
            <div class="card card-accordion card-accordion-description">
                {% block page_product_detail_accordion_description_header %}
                    {# My custom logic #}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

ABC plugin code in `tabs.html.twig` file:

```
{% sw_extends '../../../../../../../XYZ/src/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/tabs.html.twig' %}

{% block page_product_detail_tabs_inner %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <div class="detail-accordion" id="accordion">
        {% block page_product_detail_accordion_description %}
            <div class="card card-accordion card-accordion-description">
                {% block page_product_detail_accordion_description_header %}
                    {# My new custom logic to append #}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, this code is not working.

Comment: Would be nice if you would accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% sw_extends '../../../../../../../XYZ/src/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/tabs.html.twig' %}
```

this is wrong.

You have to extend `@Storefront` in both cases and make sure that you your plugins are loaded in the right sequence.
So if you first load your plugin `ABC` then `XYZ` is automatically able to extend the template of `ABC`.

**Updated answer**
Plugins are getting loaded in the order of the installation date (currently v6.4).

Comment: how to load the plugins in a sequence?

Comment: I think this makes up for a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627911/in-which-order-are-shopware-6-plugins-loaded

Comment: Seems to be the installation order https://stackoverflow.com/a/66628248/288568

Comment: It looks like the first installed module has higher priority than the last installed module. I would have found the opposite more intuitive. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902189/override-twig-template-from-plugin