# How to prority route

Tags: symfony, symfony5, shopware, shopware6

I have overwritten the controller in the application by overwritten route and it works,
but also installed another plugin that overwritten the same route as I overwritten (this plugin cannot be changed) and now this route is supported by the shopware, not mine.

this is my controller I want to display

```
namespace MyPlugin\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel;

...
class ChangeCustomerProfileRoute extends AbstractChangeCustomerProfileRoute
{
     * @Route(path="/store-api/account/change-profile", name="store-api.account.change-profile", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function change(RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context, CustomerEntity $customer): SuccessResponse

...
```

this is controller in a another plugin -I don’t want to show it
(I need this plugin because I need functionalities, but I don’t need this route)

```
namespace StorePlugin\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel;

...
class ChangeCustomerProfileRoute extends AbstractChangeCustomerProfileRoute
{
     * @Route(path="/store-api/account/change-profile", name="store-api.account.change-profile", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function change(RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context, CustomerEntity $customer): SuccessResponse

...
```

I have read this article https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority but it does not work because this do not prioritize the name, only url.

How can I prioritize my route name to be supported by shopware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority should be dependent on the plugin loading order, which is determined by [the installation date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66628248/288568).

Try to install the plugin in a different order. You could also manually change the installation date in the `plugin` table in the database.

Comment: Finally used a decorator for the class and set decoration priority. Then it works correct. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

as a hack, i would try to use a Listen and ignore the Route from Shopware.