# How can I influence the template load order in Shopware 6.4.13.0

Tags: shopware6

This is related to [In which order are Shopware 6 plugins loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627911/in-which-order-are-shopware-6-plugins-loaded)

When overwriting templates in different plugins, the load order matters and depends on plugin installation date.

I believe in the recent Shopware version it is possible to solve this in a better way.

How is this working?

Comment: There was a close vote - how can I add more focus? Some advice appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add since the last version a `getTemplatePriority` to your Bundle class. The returned integer is used for sorting. https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/ad0535de2042c2c8cbb5c4f203780feae3ba0c70

```php
public function getTemplatePriority(): int
{
    return 500;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the bundle class?

Comment: Your main plugin class extends the Shopware Bundle class. In plugin case, just add it to your plugin class where also the install, update. methods are

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it by plugin way because theme always has higher priority of views than plugins.

You should create an extend theme (child theme) https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/add-theme-inheritance

Then you can easily overwriting templates current theme.

```
...
"views": [
     "@Storefront",
     "@Plugins",
     "@SwagBasicExampleTheme",
     "@SwagBasicExampleThemeExtend"
  ],
```

Comment: You cannot influence the detailed order of the plugins this way.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot do it by plugin way because theme always has higher priority of views than plugins.

In your plugin you can add an empty template that extends from another plugin, then use this template in your plugin, as an alias.