# Difference in Twig Rendering between Local <-> Staging

Tags: debugging, twig, shopware6

We have a problem on a staging system which the same code, same composer.lock, composer install done, cache flushed.

I even activated `FroshDevelopmentHelper` on Staging and set it to ENV=dev to be able to see more debugging infos.

On Staging:

```
<!-- BLOCK BEGIN base_body_inner (custom/plugins/OurTheme/src/Resources/views/storefront/base.html.twig) -->
```

On Local (there the feature works):

```
<!-- BLOCK BEGIN base_body_inner (vendor/store.shopware.com/moorlfoundation/src/Resources/views/storefront/base.html.twig)
```

We also ensure a consistent plugin loading order by setting the `installed_at`, but that is also the same order on both system

The database was also copied from Staging (just base URL changed after the local import) + rebuilt storefront and admin.

Does anybody have a pointer what else could influcence the loading order or cause such a problem?

EDIT:

I added some debug code here:

```
vi vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Adapter/Twig/NamespaceHierarchy/BundleHierarchyBuilder.php +52

asort($extensions);
dd($extensions);  # added
```

This gives me different results on both systems.

Before Shopware loaded the templates according to installation date - now the [TemplatePriority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879643/how-can-i-influence-the-template-load-order-in-shopware-6-4-13-0) is used, which is in most cases 0, so my theory is, that a kind of chaotic order is constructed, if the TemplatePriority is not set anyhwere.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're pointing to. The only big difference I see is that the paths are different?

Comment: Yes, the paths. Instead of loading the template from the vendor/ plugin, it's loading it from the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure, [this new feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72880404/288568) is the reason:

Since 6.4.13.0 it is possible to set the load order of templates using the template priority. This was a shortcomming for a while and we are very happy about this fix.

Unfortunately it breaks our workflow, where we currently hard-code the plugin `installed_at` date and assumed that the templates are loaded in a certain way.

[image: XKCD Comic about breaking a workflow by a fix]

Follow up: [Set template priority for 3rd party plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139882/set-template-priority-for-3rd-party-plugins)

See also: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-23822