# Is there a way to add priority to plugins having translations?

Tags: plugins, translation, shopware, shopware6

We're using the `Shopware Language Pack` plugin to get more translations, but some of our plugin's translations don't get used anymore. This is because the language pack has it's own translations which somehow have a priority above ours. Can this be changed so that our plugin's translations always overwrite the language pack translations?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627911/in-which-order-are-shopware-6-plugins-loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the `DbalKernelPluginLoader` you can find that plugins are sorted by the `installed_at` column of the table `plugin`. This is also the order they are loaded in. So you may change the date of that field to change the order. Unfortunately as of today there is no option in the web-interface or plugin api to change the load priority in another way.