# Shopware 6 template inheritance issue

Tags: shopware

I have a Plugin that adds something to the Product detail page and I want to make some changes to it.
That shouldn't be a problem, right? I just can do that in my Theme, but NO that doesn't work!
Here are the views attribute of my theme.json

```
 "views": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@Plugins",
    "@MegaTmlTheme",
    "@MegaTrainingProducts"
  ],
```

And here is a Screenshot of the Profiler (Template Inheritance)
I want to change the accessory-product.html.twig, but as you can see, the Plugin template is loaded after the one from the Theme.
WHY? And how do I fix that?

[image: profiler template inheritance]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a template multiple inheritance in Shopware 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582004/how-to-do-a-template-multiple-inheritance-in-shopware-6)

Answer (score 0):

In which order did you install Plugin and Theme?

The order seems to be depenend on the installation date.

See also

[How to do a template multiple inheritance in Shopware 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582004/how-to-do-a-template-multiple-inheritance-in-shopware-6?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and

[In which order are Shopware 6 plugins loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627911/in-which-order-are-shopware-6-plugins-loaded)