# Override twig template from plugin

Tags: twig, shopware

I would like to override a block from a twig template from a plugin in my own plugin.
I have overridden native shopware templates in the past, but I have troubles with plugin templates.

The plugin I am trying to adjust is FroshProductCompare and I am also using FroshDevelopmentHelper to easily retrieve the template I am trying to adjust.

Via the development helper, I found out that the template is located at

```
vendor/store.shopware.com/froshproductcompare/src/Resources/views/storefront/component/compare/section/overview.html.twig
```

So I created the file at

```
custom/plugins/ExamplePlugin/Resources/views/storefront/component/compare/section/overview.html.twig
```

and added

```
{% sw_extends "@FroshProductCompare/storefront/component/compare/section/overview.html.twig" %}
```

to the first line of the file.

I have also tried

```
{% sw_extends "@Storefront/storefront/component/compare/section/overview.html.twig" %}
```

I have built the storefront and cleared the cache multiple times and I have also reinstalled the plugins in different orders without success.

I found similar questions, which are not the same.
E.G. [How to do a template multiple inheritance in Shopware 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582004/how-to-do-a-template-multiple-inheritance-in-shopware-6)
But the difference here is, that the block is not native to shopware and is created by the plugin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is most likely due to plugin load order.

**tl;dr**: Older plugins (based on installation date) take precedence over newer plugins. But if you want to make sure your plugins take precedence defined the load order in your theme.

It starts with finding the right template in `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Twig\TemplateFinder::find` you can see a queue is build based `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Twig\TemplateFinder::getNamespaceHierarchy` which in turn gets it from `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Twig\NamespaceHierarchy\NamespaceHierarchyBuilder`. The method return the first found template to the order is the key.

The NamespaceHierarchyBuilder is tagged with `shopware.twig.hierarchy_builder` which is used to inject the following builders:

- `Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Twig\NamespaceHierarchy\BundleHierarchyBuilder` with priority 1000
- `Shopware\Storefront\Theme\Twig\ThemeNamespaceHierarchyBuilder` with priority 500

Since you want to overwrite a template from a plugin with a plugin BundleHierarchyBuilder is the interesting one (all plugins are simply symfony bundles).

BundleHierarchyBuilder is getting the bundles from the kernel (`\Shopware\Core\Kernel`). The kernel registers the bundles in `\Shopware\Core\Kernel::registerBundles` and uses an instance of `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\KernelPluginLoader\KernelPluginLoader` to load the plugins. The used instance is `\Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\KernelPluginLoader\DbalKernelPluginLoader` as you can see in `\Shopware\Core\HttpKernel::createPluginLoader`.

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66628248/8374833) DbalKernelPluginLoader loads the plugins based on the installation date. So plugins with an older installation date will be higher up in the list in the TemplateFinder and their template will be returned.

I would actually recommend you [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67841990/8374833): Define the load order in your own theme.

Comment: Thanks for the great explenation. In our case (I am a a colleague of MweisIMI) the Theme is a 3rd party theme, so I think the https://stackoverflow.com/a/67841990/8374833 would not work. Another approach would be to try to mantain a proper installation date for the plugins, but the theme.json approach is better.

Comment: You can create your own theme and extend/inherit from your 3rd party theme as described in [the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/add-theme-inheritance) there you can have your plugin take precedence over the 3rd party plugin that you'd like to overwrite.